# Why don't we have magic numbers for shell scripts?

Tags: scripts, files, file-format

Ubuntu and Unix systems in general use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) to specify a file's type, so that e.g. VLC will open a `.mp4` file even if the extension is stripped from the file name. However in scripts the [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) serves the very same purpose.

Why don't we have individual magic numbers for `bash`, `perl`, `sed`, `awk`, … scripts as well?

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question, but the [`execve(2)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man2/execve.2.html) man page describes how the system launches scripts.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks! I learned that the shebang actually *is* the magic number, or at least `#!`, kind of. Does that mean a text file without a shebang has no magic number? How does the system know it has to run a text editor then? Or *does* a text file have a magic number and `#!` just rules/replaces it?

Comment: I think that's less of a "magic number" configuration than it is a desktop environment configuration setting.

Answer (score 3):

All scripts like bash, perl or sed are using the format ASCII text while mp4 are read as binary. Having different file header at binary level and dependant of the language while the content remain a text doesn't make sense as that means having specific software for opening each file type. Having a simple declaration in the file is enough and ensures that the script can be opened in any text editor.